# Why can I invoke my API Gateway endpoint from terminal but not from Braintree's console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http-post, aws-api-gateway, braintree

I have an API Gateway that invokes a lambda function. I deployed the gateway and am succesfully invoking the function from my terminal by sending a POST request to the endpoint. I do this like so:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"bt_signature\":\"curl\",\"bt_payload\":\"abcsdsddsd\"}"  https://*myendpointurl*
```

When I enter this endpoint in my Braintree console though as a webhook url though and click "check url" i get the following error pop up:

```
Last delivery unsuccessful. Invalid server response 400
```

It is weird that it works when I invoke it from my terminal but not here. Futhermore when i enter my endpoint for the method in my web browser it turns up with this error message:

```
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

I have double checked I am using the write endpoint for this specific POST method. It's just weird that it works from terminal but not as a webhook url in braintree. Ideas?

Comment: That should be addressed to Braintree support I think since we don't have any visibility of what they are POSTing (check CloudWatch Logs though).

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get "Missing Authentication Token" when hitting from the browser is because the browser will make a GET request, whereas your API is setup for POST method. API Gateway will respond with a "Missing Authentication Token" when you make requests for non-existent resources/methods. (It's possible Braintree is also generating a GET request internally, but I would recommend you check with their support for confirmation.)

Hope this helps,
Ritisha.